# Mean and avg returning argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform some actions on this list.

`(17.4251815838109, 17.0936532111551, 16.9495499311632, 16.9611733013071, 18.8336948935771, 17.646153581097, 19.2786685060239, 16.4914103149693, 17.408398785738, 12.2516802707903, 8.20875224602797, 9.83287443240513, 12.378605268717, 9.63945989984414, 12.0650540857786, 9.29632838256577, 9.25157954403105, 11.0929656911906, 37.807554672932, 41.950573790796, 35.2520444352789, 37.6890665803607, 41.8401126788036, 35.3467674884495, 37.0492529214895, 41.6349870612264, 35.6520402549855, 38.5136275773283, 
38.0826940746784, 40.1021729700702, 34.389833834103, 37.8720309134135, 42.0279685436462, 36.9470427712744, 39.5936166772303, 37.3812431579907, 37.7908205703833, 10.2308875354996, 7.9992825801163, 10.2634414491813, 6.21692151856682, 11.4808194246271, 10.3143892972944, 7.85839509257254, 10.0939357755023, 7.18990234634676, 9.00739367017116, 11.2214020156087, 6.55053090008927, 10.1296398736156, 9.51315411219287, 9.38005451274706, 10.362011558752, 9.2644017333158, 9.61363970611778, 9.61679053614169, 14.4235421208885)`

I'm trying to get the avg and then the mean

```
avg: Subsets of abs[] are averaged, where each subset consist of those observations with the same factor levels. 

mean: average...

e <- mean(ave(abs))
```

Here is the error that I got

```
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(ave(abs)) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `ave` is not the average; that's a very different function. And normally the "average" is the same as the mean. How are they different to you?

Comment: I know. that's what i mentioned there as well, right? :)

Comment: avg: Subsets of abs[] are averaged, where each subset consist of those observations with the same factor levels. 
Where as, mean is the average.

Comment: Well your sample data doesn't show any factor levels. Where are those coming from?

Comment: What does factor levels mean?

Comment: Well, you included that text in your question, so I assume you know what that means. If your question is just about factors, then ask that instead. I really don't know what you are asking because it doesn't seem like you have all the information. Is this something you are trying to do on your data or is this some kind of homework problem?

Comment: This is a code that I found online. and I'm trying to process data with it. I seem to be having problems there.

Comment: It sure does. If you don't have some sort of factor that divides your data into different groups. Using `ave` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: How do I mean the data? if not avg. it. Would jsut avg (list) do?

Comment: There is no `avg` function. If you have a vector `v<-1:5` then you can find the mean with `mean(v)`

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: I literally just gave you an example. `v` is a vector with the values 1,2,3,4,5. Then if you run `mean(v)` you will get `3` which is the mean (or "average") of those 5 values.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you have your data as a list. The function `mean` does not work on lists and attempting to do so will result in `NA` being returned along with the warning `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`.